# must for deduction

Tags: modal-verbs

A situation where Jack , Bob and Adam at the same room ,Bob and Adam thought that Jack didn't understand English , Bob said to Adam: "Jack is so boring" , Jack get mad and left the room, then Adam said: "**You upset him , Jack must know English"**

I want to know if the usage of must in what Adam said is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one use of "must" is "to show that you think something is very likely or certain to be true"  ([cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/must_1) second meaning) We use must when we made a logical deduction from the evidence

"Jack must know English" = It is very likely that Jack knows English. I have worked this out from the evidence that he reacted when you said something in English.